# Sitecore Admin Search does not work after Solr integration

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore

We have integrated Solr with our Sitecore instance. We realise that the admin searches are not working after that as show in the screenshot below. We used the official Solr-Sitecore integration guides for our installation, and do not seem to miss out on any config listed. The search will work when we re-enable the Lucene-related config files and disable the Solr-related config files.

Sitecore version : 8.0 Update 5
Solr version : 4.10.3

Do note we have also tried rebuilding database links, search index and also indexes through the Indexing manager.

Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Error log:

[image]

Comment: Any error in the log file?

Comment: What is your SOLR url and other Solr-related settings? (and Solr log, if possible). Is Solr accessible through the regular web interface on <ip>/solr ?

Comment: @MatsLindh Hi, Solr is accessible through the regular web interface. Solr related settings I had followed exactly as the official guide.

Comment: @JanBluemink I had just added the error log message onto the main thread. Thanks